# Quotients of successive powers of the augmentation ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

For $H$ be any group, let $\mathbb{Z} H$ denote the integral group ring. Define $J(H)$ to be the augmentation ideal i.e $J$ is the kernel of the ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}H \to \mathbb{Z}$ sending each element to the sum of its coefficients. Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$ define $A^n(H) = J(H)^n / J(H)^{n+1}$ ($A^n(H)$ is usually referred to as the $n^{th}$ augmentation quotient).

Now suppose we have a direct product of groups $G = G_1 \times G_2$. I wish to prove that there exists an isomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules 
$A^n(G) \cong \bigoplus_{i + j = n} A^i(G_1) \otimes A^j(G_2)$.

So far I have shown that the canonical isomorphism of algebras $\mathbb{Z}[G_1 \times G_2] \cong \mathbb{Z} G_1 \otimes \mathbb{Z} G_1 $ sends $J(G_1 \times G_2)^n$ to $\sum_{i+j = n} J(G_1)^i \otimes J(G_2)^j$ but I am unsure of how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated.